# How do I do a B43 Legacy install on Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I recently installed ubuntu onto an extra hard drive and everything booted correctly. However, my Linksys wireless card is not working. I went though all the forums and walk throughs and I know that I need to install the b43 legacy firmware to get the card to work.

When I try to install the files, I keep getting the message in Terminal saying "No such file or directory" for every file i need to run. It's Ubuntu 11.10 on a dell optiplex gx280. Also, the "pool" file that is supposed to be on the file system is not there

Comment: Could you update your question with the commands you're trying to run? If you're following a particular walkthrough, posting a link to it would also be useful. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43%20-%20No%20Internet%20access walkthrough.The section b43 - no internet access

Answer (score 1):

Did You try to run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43legacy-installer
```

However most of the broadcom wireless cards will need this package:

```
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you browsing files on the install media (CD/Pendrive), as indicated on the help page?

You can download b43-fwcutter package from launchpad and copy to your computer. Depending on your architecture, you will need:

[32bit](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/b43-fwcutter_014-9_i386.deb) or [64bit](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/b43-fwcutter_014-9_amd64.deb) version

Once downloaded, open terminal and navigate to the folder where your file is. For example, if it's in your Downloads folder, enter following command:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

Once in the folder, install the software:

```
sudo dpkg -i b43-fwcutter*
```

Restart computer and if it doesn't work then follow instructions on the help page starting from step 2